# Arduino using Ethernet shield WebClient example code is not working

Tags: ethernet

I'm using an Arduino Uno and Ethernet shield with the WIZnet chip W5100. The WebServer code example is working. DHCP is working, the Ethernet shield is receiving an IP address from the Linksys modem "router" and everything is fine.

But I cannot connect to a web site using the WebClient code. I found out that `client.connect(server, 80);` is returning -1 "Time_OUT" and it is supposed to return 1 according to the Arduino Ethernet library.

I tried connecting to different websites. I tried assigning an IP address manually, not using DHCP. I tried making pin 4 of the SD memory card SPI to output `pinMode(4, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(4, HIGH);` But it doesn't work. I get on my Serial line connection failed or it returns "connected" then "Disconnecting..." immediately after because `client.connect` has returned -1.

The example code I'm using:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0x28, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xB9, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:

  Serial.println("connecting...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.print(client.connect(server,80));
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Using a local server IP address like my router's IP address, the connection works. But the issue is mainly in the WAN. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using numeric server IP address (i.e. `server(74,125,232,128)`)?

Comment: Also, `Serial.print(client.connect(server,80));` seems to establish a second connection without using the first one. Did you want to print a string on the terminal instead of actually running the function?

Comment: Before adding this line it was the same issue this line is just returning the result for me. Yes i used numeric ip so i wont use DNS and doesn't work. Im afraid its a modem issue because the same setup with the same shield and same arudino with the same code worked on another network.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev By the way my shield came without a mac address printed on it and i'm using a random mac address. Could this be an issue?

Comment: [Don't cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185056/arduino-webclient-example-is-not-working)

Comment: @gre_gor i didn't know about the Arduino stackexchange is already found i will delete it from stackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.print(client.connect(server,80));
    ...
```

If the first call to `client.connect()` succeeds, you call it again immediately, and the error message you're seeing comes from that second call. This really is not surprising — I can't imagine a scenario in which that would actually work.

What you really want is something more like:

```
if (result = client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.print(result);
    ...
```

Comment: This is not an issue Dave your way will work and my way is working. Im just retrieving the result and it is working and writing -1 on the serial line.

Comment: That's strange ... I could've sworn that you said it wasn't working. My bad. In that case, we'll send this over to Arduino.SE where they might be able to help you with the details of that particular library.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried also using the ip address i get no result at all from the client.connect() so connection fails.

Comment: Have you tried getting the result code like he suggested? Using the IPAddress and not the string, if it still doesn't connect and nothing is printed, then it means `connect()` returns 0. Try opening the EthernetClient source and adding a few `print()`s in `connect()` to find out the exact condition that causes the 0 return code. Though this looks like a connection issue since `getHostByName()` is failing just like `connect()`. You sure your modem is connected to the net?

Comment: @TisteAndii thanks for your help. The issue was in the mac address. Because my shield has no mac address and i was using a well known manufacturer mac address so it wasn't completing the connection with the google server and it was dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem:

The problem was in the mac address itself. When i used the mac address given by the example itself the connection didn't fail and `client.connect()` returned 1.

I used this mac address instead of the one in the code above:

```
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
```